# Github - Merging is blocked

Tags: git, github

I have multiple branches: `master`, `development` and `stav`. (There is only one developer in the repository at the moment - me).

`master` and `development` branches are fully protected (all the checkboxes are selected). I need to push to `stav` and create a pull request for merging to `development`.

`stav` branch have `development` branch chanages:

[image]

```
*   47e7341 - (21 minutes ago) Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/development' into stav - stav alfi (HEAD -> stav, origin/stav)
|\
| *   afa89f6 - (30 minutes ago) Merge pull request #1 from UniversityFinalProjects/stav - stavalfi (origin/development)
| |\
* | | cd93730 - (25 minutes ago) 8 - stav alfi
| |/
|/|
* | 9336798 - (51 minutes ago) 8 - stav alfi
* | c2c240e - (60 minutes ago) 7 - stav alfi
* | 8104fdb - (81 minutes ago) 6 - stav alfi
* | d48f373 - (83 minutes ago) 5 - stav alfi
* | 7bac29b - (3 hours ago) 4 - stav alfi (master)
|/
* cfc2572 - (6 hours ago) 1 - stav alfi (origin/master, topic, development)
* 686e526 - (6 hours ago) Initial commit - stav alfi
```

Github doesn't let me finish the pull request:

[image]

The error:

> Merging is blocked.
>   Merging can be performed automatically with one
>   approved review.

**What does it mean? How can I fix it?**

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/ and in particular https://help.github.com/articles/about-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/

Comment: Hi @torek, I understand the reason for "Review required" error but not the "Merging is blocked" error. They both want the dsame thing - someone else to review my pull request. So why I get the same error twise? I'm sure I'm missing something or I dont fully understand what the error massages mean.

Comment: "Review required" is the *reason* that "merging is blocked". Once the review is done, both errors will be cleared-up. In other words the first one is merely *explaining* the second one: the second is a condition (about which ordinary, non-admin users can do nothing) and the first is a reason—possibly one of several—about which ordinary users *can* do something. So the messages are for different users and different purposes, even if they are about the same underlying condition.

Comment: Thanks agian toreck!

Comment: @StavAlfi I was about to write that: the "Merging is blocked" error does mention "Merging can be performed automatically with one approved review"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That comes from late 2015 "[Protected branches and required status checks](https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks)" where protected branch can have required status checks.

See "[About required status checks](https://help.github.com/articles/about-required-status-checks/)" and "[About required reviews for pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/)"

> If a person with admin permissions chooses the Request changes option in a review, then that person must approve the pull request before it can be merged

Note: a [review can be dismissed](https://help.github.com/articles/dismissing-a-pull-request-review/) (although only by the owner/admin of the repo).

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pull_requests/merge_box/pull-request-dismiss-review-button.png]

As [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497780/github-merging-is-blocked/46499751#comment79963200_46497780), once a review is performed, the "Merging is blocked" cleared out automatically.

Answer (score 1):

1. "At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write
   access": This indicates that in order to merge a branch or commit
   into the main branch, you need to have at least one review from a
   reviewer who has write access to the repository. The review is
   typically performed to ensure the quality and correctness of the
   changes before they are merged.
2. "Merging is blocked": This means that the system is preventing you
   from automatically merging the changes because the required number
   of approving reviews has not been obtained yet. The system enforces
   this policy to maintain code quality and prevent unintended or
   erroneous changes from being merged.

To resolve this issue and enable the merging process, you need to follow the repository's guidelines for obtaining reviews. Typically, you would need to request a review from a colleague or a designated reviewer who has write access to the repository. Once they review and approve your changes, you should be able to proceed with the merge.

If you're not familiar with the specific guidelines or workflow for obtaining reviews in your repository, I would recommend reaching out to your team or the repository administrators for further assistance. They will be able to provide you with more specific guidance on how to proceed and successfully merge your changes.